# JVM App Pauses for many hours | No OOM error observed but all indications of sthg not working right in GC

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, jvm

I am facing an issue where my java app just PAUSES & doesn't do any activity.

VM args:  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/javadumps -Xms2048m -Xmx4600m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps

The app uses CMS & ParNew collectors for tenured and young generation.
GCdetails are available in this dropbox link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0ta7699ngpoxe7/mdoaggregatorscript.out_agg4?dl=0

> System details: 2 Xeon cores, 7.1 GB (7513700)  MemTotal:
>   7513700 kB, MemFree:         2173332 kB, Buffers:           90248 kB 
>   Cached:            67264 kB, SwapCached:            0 kB, Active:
>   5071852 kB  Inactive:         104700 kB, Active(anon):    5019152 kB

I have always observed that when the app pause occurs ParNew collection printouts starting with ParNew: are always at the last.

> 46341.116: [GC46341.116: [ParNew: 1059840K->1059840K(1059840K), 0.0000700 secs]46341.116: [CMS: 2739199K->2744012K(3532800K), 6.6278210 secs] 3799039K->2744012K(4592640K), [CMS Perm : 20858K->20858K(34852K)], 6.6281870 secs] [Times: user=6.63 sys=0.00,
>   real=6.63 secs] 
>   46347.745: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 2744012K(3532800K)] 2744045K(4592640K), 0.0015100 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00,
>   real=0.00 secs] 
>   46347.746: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
>   46352.379: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.632/4.632 secs] [Times: user=6.62 sys=0.01, real=4.63 secs] 
>   46352.379: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
>   46352.436: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.041/0.057 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.06 secs] 
>   46352.436: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]  CMS: abort preclean due to time 46357.446: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:
>   3.646/5.009 secs] [Times: user=4.52 sys=3.12, real=5.01 secs] 
>   46357.446: [GC[YG occupancy: 341596 K (1059840 K)]46357.447: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.5170340 secs]46357.964: [weak refs processing,
>   0.0000380 secs]46357.964: [scrub string table, 0.0002770 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 2744012K(3532800K)] 3085608K(4592640K), 0.5175340 secs]
>   [Times: user=1.04 sys=0.00, real=0.52 secs] 
>   46357.964: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
>   46359.386: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.422/1.422 secs] [Times: user=1.89 sys=0.47, real=1.42 secs] 
>   46359.387: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
>   46359.400: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.013/0.013 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
>   46361.400: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 2743986K(3532800K)] 3197213K(4592640K), 0.4010590 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00,
>   real=0.40 secs] 
>   46361.801: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
>   46365.768: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 3.967/3.967 secs] [Times: user=5.04 sys=0.00, real=3.97 secs] 
>   46365.768: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
>   46365.837: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.049/0.068 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.07 secs] 
>   46365.837: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]  CMS: abort preclean due to time 46370.842: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:
>   1.242/5.006 secs] [Times: user=1.70 sys=0.72, real=5.00 secs] 
>   46370.843: [GC[YG occupancy: 558264 K (1059840 K)]46370.843: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.8305230 secs]46371.674: [weak refs processing,
>   0.0000380 secs]46371.674: [scrub string table, 0.0002770 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 2743986K(3532800K)] 3302250K(4592640K), 0.8310160 secs]
>   [Times: user=1.65 sys=0.00, real=0.83 secs] 
>   46371.674: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
>   46373.235: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.561/1.561 secs] [Times: user=2.08 sys=0.48, real=1.57 secs] 
>   46373.235: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
>   46373.251: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs] 
>   46375.252: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 2743585K(3532800K)] 3436745K(4592640K), 0.6207210 secs] [Times: user=0.62 sys=0.00,
>   real=0.62 secs] 
>   46375.872: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
>   46380.253: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 4.381/4.381 secs] [Times: user=5.64 sys=0.46, real=4.38 secs] 
>   46380.254: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
>   46380.364: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.080/0.111 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.07, real=0.11 secs] 
>   46380.364: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]  CMS: abort preclean due to time 46385.369: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean:
>   1.233/5.004 secs] [Times: user=1.84 sys=0.86, real=5.01 secs] 
>   46385.370: [GC[YG occupancy: 845719 K (1059840 K)]46385.370: [Rescan (parallel) , 1.2891210 secs]46386.659: [weak refs processing,
>   0.0000390 secs]46386.659: [scrub string table, 0.0002680 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 2743585K(3532800K)] 3589305K(4592640K), 1.2896320 secs]
>   [Times: user=2.55 sys=0.00, real=1.29 secs] 
>   46386.659: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
>   46388.213: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 1.554/1.554 secs] [Times: user=2.31 sys=0.35, real=1.55 secs] 
>   46388.213: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
>   46388.235: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.021/0.021 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
>   46389.132: [GC46389.132: [ParNew: 942080K->116318K(1059840K), 0.1032530 secs] 3685661K->2859899K(4592640K), 0.1034550 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.00, real=0.10 secs] 
>   46435.520:  [GC46435.520: [ParNew: 1058398K->29773K(1059840K), 0.1435140 secs] 3801979K->2773355K(4592640K), 0.1437390 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.00, real=0.15 secs] 
>   46488.172: [GC46488.172: [ParNew: 971853K->18413K(1059840K), 0.1826040 secs] 3715435K->2761995K(4592640K), 0.1828270 secs] [Times: user=0.37
>   sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs] 
>   46530.228: [GC46530.228: [ParNew: 960493K->18608K(1059840K), 0.2217660 secs] 3704075K->2762190K(4592640K), 0.2219740 secs] [Times: user=0.44
>   sys=0.00, real=0.23 secs] 
>   46574.685: [GC46574.685: [ParNew: 960688K->23663K(1059840K), 0.2601680 secs] 3704270K->2767245K(4592640K), 0.2603980 secs] [Times: user=0.52
>   sys=0.00, real=0.26 secs] 
>   46617.432: [GC46617.432: [ParNew: 965743K->31418K(1059840K), 0.2988910 secs] 3709325K->2775000K(4592640K), 0.2990950 secs] [Times: user=0.60
>   sys=0.00, real=0.29 secs] 
>   46661.564: [GC46661.564: [ParNew: 973498K->38269K(1059840K), 0.3438770 secs] 3717080K->2788322K(4592640K), 0.3441020 secs] [Times: user=0.68
>   sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs] 
>   46702.866: [GC46702.866: [ParNew: 980349K->24715K(1059840K), 0.3445660 secs] 3730402K->2779810K(4592640K), 0.3447720 secs] [Times: user=0.68
>   sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs] 
>   46747.238: [GC46747.239: [ParNew: 966795K->35986K(1059840K), 0.3594350 secs] 3721890K->2796065K(4592640K), 0.3596770 secs] [Times: user=0.70
>   sys=0.00, real=0.36 secs] 
>   46791.978: [GC46791.978: [ParNew: 978066K->23342K(1059840K), 0.3379110 secs] 3738145K->2788380K(4592640K), 0.3381030 secs] [Times: user=0.67
>   sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs]

(When stuck jstat gccause output:
sudo /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/bin/jstat -gccause 31927 10000

> S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT
>   GCT    LGCC                 GCC
>    19.82   0.00  60.89  78.27  59.86   1358 1038.979  1348 1441.695 2480.674 Allocation Failure   No GC
>    19.82   0.00  60.89  78.27  59.86   1358 1038.979  1348 1441.695 2480.674 Allocation Failure   No GC

I am having 2 pointers here: 
concurrent mode failure & ParNew (promotion failed)
But all the pauses I have observed the gc output ending with

46702.866: [GC46702.866: [ParNew: 980349K->24715K(1059840K), 0.3445660 secs] 3730402K->2779810K(4592640K), 0.3447720 secs] [Times: user=0.68 sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs] 
46747.238: [GC46747.239: [ParNew: 966795K->35986K(1059840K), 0.3594350 secs] 3721890K->2796065K(4592640K), 0.3596770 secs] [Times: user=0.70 sys=0.00, real=0.36 secs] 
46791.978: [GC46791.978: [ParNew: 978066K->23342K(1059840K), 0.3379110 secs] 3738145K->2788380K(4592640K), 0.3381030 secs] [Times: user=0.67 sys=0.00, real=0.34 secs]

Brief about the app: The app creates 4 thread pools and in total 350 threads and each does parallel writing to the datastore. All the memory intensive objects that are created in the threads are all inside the call method of threads and hence there is no memory leak as once the thread is done they are ready for garbage collection.

Comment: can you take threaddump when it is paused ?

Comment: Thnxs Jigar for replying. I am really stuck on this problem and don't have any pointers on why it is happening.
                                                           
JStack output: <https://www.dropbox.com/s/07qr8lysilqrdlo/jstackdump_agg2.txt?dl=0>

                                                                  
GC Output:
<https://www.dropbox.com/s/sz60zd8ungj3jp3/mdoaggregatorscript.out_agg2?dl=0>

Comment: can you check if there is a deadlock ? using Jconsole

Comment: There is one thing I have observed everytime the pause happens:


3833.465: [GC3833.465: [ParNew: 980076K->24445K(1059840K), 0.3600860 secs] 3733247K->2782549K(4592640K), 0.3603280 secs] [Times: user=0.72 sys=0.00, real=0.36 secs] 
3899.305: [GC3899.305: [ParNew: 966525K->35385K(1059840K), 0.3609730 secs] 3724629K->2798541K(4592640K), 0.3611850 secs] [Times: user=0.72 sys=0.00, real=0.36 secs] 
3974.391: [GC3974.391: [ParNew: 977465K->22880K(1059840K), 0.3534330 secs] 3740621K->2790943K(4592640K), 0.3536440 secs] [Times: user=0.70 sys=0.00, real=0.36 secs] 
2014-10-28 19:43:37

Comment: There is no deadlock.I already checked using your kit java profiler.

Comment: are you saying that it is just GC pause  and nothing in app threads ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63977/discussion-between-unilocal-and-jigar-joshi).